# column name error while inserting data

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I've the below code to insert data into an Excel sheet.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
Connection con = null;
Statement stmnt = null;
try
{
    int updateQuery=0;
    String a=request.getParameter("comments");
    String b=request.getParameter("updatedl");
    String c=request.getParameter("sid");
    String d=request.getParameter("desc");
    String e=request.getParameter("pubcode");
    String f=request.getParameter("Type");
    String g=request.getParameter("status");
    String h=request.getParameter("DateRec");
    String i=request.getParameter("startD");
    String j=request.getParameter("AssignedD");
    String k=request.getParameter("sentToAE");
    String l=request.getParameter("RespFrmAE");
    String m=request.getParameter("VWRCmp");
    String n=request.getParameter("PS");
    String o=request.getParameter("TEst");
    String p=request.getParameter("Units");
    String q=request.getParameter("VWR");
    String r=request.getParameter("IE");
    String s=request.getParameter("RevDate");
    String t=request.getParameter("ReviewS");


Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/jus/Excel1.xls; ReadOnly=False;");


stmnt = con.createStatement(); 
//String query="select column_name from 'Feb$'";
String query = "insert into [Feb$] ('Comments','No of lines updated in PSIS','Shipment ID',"+
"'SAP TXT Description', 'Phoenix Pub Code', 'Product Type', 'Status of the job', 'Date Request received',"+
"'Start Date', 'Date assigned', 'Date file sent to AE', 'Date response from AE',"+
"'Date completed --VWR', 'Assigned to PS', 'Time Estimate', 'Units', 'Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)',"+
"'Internal Errors', 'Review Date',  'Review Sent (Yes/No)') values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?S)";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, a);
ps.setString(2, b);
ps.setString(3, c);
ps.setString(4, d);
ps.setString(5, e);
ps.setString(6, f);
ps.setString(7, g);
ps.setString(8, h);
ps.setString(9, i);
ps.setString(10, j);
ps.setString(11, k);
ps.setString(12, l);
ps.setString(13, m);
ps.setString(14, n);
ps.setString(15, o);
ps.setString(16, p);
ps.setString(17, q);
ps.setString(18, r);
ps.setString(19, s);
ps.setString(20, t);

//out.print(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
<br>
<TABLE style="background-color: #E3E4FA;" 
WIDTH="30%" border="1">
   <tr><th>Data is inserted successfully 
 in database.</th></tr>
</table>
<%
}

}
catch( Exception e )
{
out.println( e );
}
finally
{
try
{
stmnt.close();
con.close();
}
catch( Exception e )
{
out.println( e );
}
}

        %>
```

and i'm getting the below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: ''No of lines updated in PSIS''. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.
```

and my excel sheet is of the below column names.

```
Comments
No of lines updated in PSIS
Shipment ID
SAP TXT Description
Phoenix Pub Code
Product Type
Status of the job
Date Request received
Start Date
Date assigned
Date file sent to AE
Date response from AE
Date completed --VWR
Assigned to PS
Time Estimate
Units
Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)
Internal Errors
Review Date
Review Sent (Yes/No)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you code has some problem in insert part of the query building.

1 first what is [Feb$]?
2. your last parameter is i think mis typed like "?s" it should be like only "?,?,?"

Comment: hey thanks this worked, but i've got another error. it is `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]COUNT field incorrect `

Comment: if you are inserting a data it won't return you a resultset instead of it will return int value.